# How would you solve this differential equation: $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{100}{y}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{100}{y}$$

Also if $y = f(x)$,

$f'(0) = 0$ and $f(0) = 10$

How would you solve this for $y$?

Comment: The first idea that comes to my mind is to multiply both sides by $y'$ and integrate. But this leads to an order 1ODE which I can't solve at first sight. So this is probably a well-known type of ODE which I forgot...

Comment: What are the initial conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y''=\frac {100} y$$
is autonomous (ie $x$ is not present in the equation). The standard procedure therefore is to substitute $u(y)=y'$ with
$$ y'' = \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = u'u $$
solve
$$ u'u = 100/y $$
with $u'u = \frac{1}{2}(u^2)'$ we get
$$ u(y)^2 = 2\left(c_1 + 100\ln(y)\right). $$
This equation "can be integrated"
$$ y' = \pm\sqrt{2\left(c_1 + 100\ln(y)\right)} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\left(c_1 + 100\ln(y)\right)}}dy = \mp\int 1\,dx $$
This is the point where it gets ugly...

The integral can be evaluated to
$$ \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{200}} e^{-c_1/100}\operatorname{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{100}+\ln(y)}\right) + c_2 = \mp x $$
where $\operatorname{erfi}$ is the imaginary error function. Solve for $y$ and you are done...

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $y'$ and integrate. You will get here:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm\sqrt{2k_1+200\log (y)}$$
$$\int^x\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2k_1+200\log (y)}}=x+k_2$$

That is not an elementary integral, you can't get a solution as elementary functions. Wolfram uses the error function to give a solution that has no integrals in it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to that of the user example, but I though this answer might give you so more intuition about how to solve similar problems and when certain things are equal to each other.

In physics when you have a dynamic system where the force/acceleration on an object only depends on its position, then the [potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy#Derivable_from_a_potential) of that object will also only be a function of its position and energy will be conserved. In this case the force $F$ can be expressed as follows

$$
y'' = F = -\nabla U(y) = \frac{100}{y},
$$

such that the potential $U(y)$ can be found with

$$
U(y) = -\int{\frac{100}{y}dy} = -100 \log{y} + c_1.
$$

In physics the conservation of energy means that the sum of the kinetic energy and potential energy are constant

$$
\frac{y'^2}{2} - 100 \log{y} + c_1 = c_2,
$$

$$
y' = \frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{200 \log{y} + c_3}.
$$

By applying [separation of variables](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeparationofVariables.html) the solution can be found with

$$
\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{200 \log{y} + c_3}} = x + c_4,
$$

which has the implicit solution

$$
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{200}} e^{-\frac{c_3}{200}} \text{erfi}\left(\frac{c_3}{200} + \log(y)\right) = x + c_4,
$$

where $\text{erfi}(x)$ is the [imaginary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html) ($\text{erfi}(x) = -i\, \text{erf}(i\, x)$). Rewriting this to an expression for $y(x)$ yields

$$
y(x) = \exp\left(\text{erfi}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{200}{\pi}} e^{\frac{c_3}{200}} (x + c_4)\right) - \frac{c_3}{200}\right).
$$

Answer (score -2):

Wolfram alpha gives [this result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%2ay%27%27+%3D+100) which shows it is not easy to find.